# How to explain this contradiction about Weyl group of $SL_n(K)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

I have some difficulties in understanding why the Weyl group of algebraic group $SL_n(K)$ is isomorphic to symmetric group $S_n$.

Let $G=SL_n(K)$ be the simply-connected algebraic group over the algebraic closed filed $K$ with $charK>2$. Also let $T$ be the maximal tori of $G$ consists of diagonal matrices with determinant 1. In this case, we have $W=N_G(T)/T$ is the Weyl group of $G$ in which $N_G(T)$ is the group of generalized permutation matrices with determinant 1.
On the other hand, it is well-known that Weyl group of $G$ is isomorphic to symmetric group on $n$ letters. Hence $N_G(T)/T\cong S_n$.

**Addendum and Edition:**
Now let $S\in N_G(T)$ be corresponding to the cycle $(1~~ 2)\in S_n$. Considering the action of $S$ on $diag[a_1, a_2,..., a_n]\in T$, we get $diag[a_1, a_2,..., a_n]^S=diag[a_2, a_1, a_3,..., a_n]$. Since the determinant of a permutation matrix is just the Sign of the corresponded permutation, we have $det(S)=Sign(1~~2)=-1$ , which is impossible according to $S\in N_G(T)$.

This implies that $N_G(T)$ can not contain any element which is corresponded to $(1~~2)$. So how could I explain the isomorphism $N_G(T)/T\cong S_n$?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement about the determinant of the diagonal matrices is wrong! $\operatorname{det} \operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots, a_n)=\operatorname{det}\operatorname{diag}(a_2,a_1,a_3,\ldots,a_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Re the addendum: it's not correct that a matrix $S$ conjugating those two matrices must be a permutation matrix.  Indeed, in the case $n=2$ the matrix
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ll}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$
works, as Jyrki points out in the comments, and in general you can find elements of $N_G(T)$ implementing the permutation you want similarly.

Comment: we have $diag[a_1,a_2,..., a_n]\in T \subset SL_n(K)$. So $\prod a_i=1$. Hence $det(diag[a_2, a_1,..., a_n])=-1$ since we have switch two rows.

Comment: but you also switched two columns :)

Comment: Oh! yes, I didn't considered that:)

Comment: Sorry, but the problem still exists! If $S\in N_{SL_n(K)}(T)$ such that ${diag[a_1, a_2,..., a_n]}^S=diag[a_2, a_1,..., a_n]$, then $S$ is the permutation matrix corresponded to transposition $(1~~2)$. Now since the determinant of permutation matrix is the $Sign$ of corresponded permutation, we have $det(S)=-1$, which violates the hypothesis $S\in N_{SL_n(K)}(T)$. So how $N_{SL_n(K)}(T)$ can contain transpositions??

Comment: @user97635: The matrix
$$S=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr 1&0\cr}$$ is in $N_{SL_2(K)}(T)$, and $S^{-1}diag(a_1,a_2)S=diag(a_2,a_1)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What about the order? The order of $S$ in $N_G(T)/T$ must be 2. How can this happen?

Comment: No problem @user97635. $S^2\in T$ so the order of the coset of $S$ is two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Aha! Thank you so much.